# Nginx proxy domain to another domain with no change URL

Tags: nginx, proxypass

My question is in the subject. I have a domain, this is the nginx config for it:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name connect3.domain.ru www.connect3.domain.ru;

access_log /var/log/nginx/connect3.domain.ru.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/connect3.domain.ru.error.log;

root /home/httpd/vhosts/html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

location ~* \.(avi|bin|bmp|css|dmg|doc|docx|dpkg|exe|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|ics|img|jpeg|jpg|js|m2a|m2v|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|msi|pdf|pkg|png|pps|ppt|pptx|ps|rar|rss|rtf|swf|tif|tiff|txt|wmv|xhtml|xls|xml|zip)$ {
    root /home/httpd/vhosts/html;
    access_log off;
    expires 1d;
}

location ~ /\.(git|ht|svn) {
    deny all;
}

location / {
    #rewrite ^ http://connect2.domain.ru/;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_hide_header "Cache-Control";
    add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    proxy_hide_header "Pragma";
    add_header Pragma "no-cache";
    expires -1;
    add_header Last-Modified $sent_http_Expires;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
}
```

I need to proxy connect3.domain.ru host to connect2.domain.ru, but with no URL changed in browser's address bars. My commented out rewrite line could solve this problem, but it's just a rewrite, so I cannot stay with the same URL.

I know that this question is easy, but please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You set:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

You want:

```
proxy_set_header Host connect2.domain.ru;
```

Comment: And that's all? Need I change proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; to proxy_pass http://connect2.domain.ru:8080/; ? Or just comment out rewrite as it is and change proxy_set_header?

Comment: Tried this. No, URL changes.

Comment: *Or just comment out rewrite as it is and change proxy_set_header?*
Yeap.

Answer (score 16):

Telepathy about port 8080 has been turned off, because you don't show us the full config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name connect3.domain.ru www.connect3.domain.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://connect2.domain.ru;
        proxy_set_header Host connect2.domain.ru;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

So I think - here is the solution if I understood the problem correctly:

```
 # backend.wants.this.server.com
 # browser.shows.this.server.com

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name browser.shows.this.server.com;

  location / {
     proxy_set_header Host backend.wants.this.server.com;
     proxy_redirect http://backend.wants.this.server.com/ http://browser.shows.this.server.com/; 
  }
}
```

Comment: does this work? Or do you also need the proxy_pass directive even if you do a proxy_redirect?